# How to make RETURN trap in bash preserve the return code?

Tags: linux, bash, bash-trap

Below is the simplified scheme of the script I am writing. The program must take parameters in different ways, so there is a fine division to several functions.

The problem is that the chainloading of the return value from deeper functions breaks on the trap, where the result is to be checked to show a message.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

check_a_param() {
    [ "$1" = return_ok ] && return 0 || return 3
}

check_params() {
    # This trap should catch negative results from the functions
    #   performing actual checks, like check_a_param() below.
    return_trap() {
        local retval=$?
        [ $retval -ne 0 ] && echo 'Bad, bad… Dropping to manual setup.'
        return $retval
    }
    # check_params can be called from different functions, not only
    #   setup(). But the other functions don’t care about the return value
    #   of check_params().
    [ "${FUNCNAME[1]}" = setup ] \
        && trap "return_trap; got_retval=$?; trap - RETURN; return $got_retval;" RETURN
    check_a_param 'return_bad' || return $?
    # …
    # Here we check another parameters in the same way.
    # …
    echo 'Provided parameters are valid.'
    return 0  # To be sure.
}

ask_for_params() {
    echo 'User sets params manually step by step.'
}

setup() {
    [ "$1" = force_manual ] && local MANUAL=t
    # If gathered parameters do not pass check_params()
    #   the script shall resort to asking user for entering them.
    [ ! -v MANUAL ] && {
        check_params \
            && echo "check_params() returned with 0. Not running manual setup."
            || false
    }|| ask_for_params
    # do_the_job
}

setup "$@"  # Either empty or ‘force_manual’.
```

How it should work:

```
              ↗ 3 → 3→ trap →3                     ↗ || ask_for_params ↘
 check_a_param >>> check_params >>> [ ! -v MANUAL ]                     ↓
              ↘ 0 → 0→ trap →0                     ↘ && ____________ do_the_job
```

The idea is, if a check fails, its return code forces `check_params()` to return, too, which, in its turn would trigger the `|| ask_for_params` condition in `setup()`. But the trap returns 0:

```
              ↗ 3 → 3→ trap →0
 check_a_param >>> check_params >>> [ ! -v MANUAL ] &&… >>> do_the_job
              ↘ 0 → 0→ trap →0
```

If you try to run the script as is, you should see

```
Bad, bad… Dropping to manual setup.
check_params() returned with 0. Not running manual setup.
```

Which means that the bad result triggered the trap(!) but the mother function that has set it, didn’t pass the result.

In attempt to set a hack I’ve tried

- to set retval as a global variable `declare -g retval=$?` in the `return_trap()` and use its value in the line setting the trap. The variable is set (`[ -v retval ]` returns successfully), but …has no value. Funny.
- okay, let’s put`retval=Eeh` to the `check_params()`, outside the `return_trap()` and just set it to `$?` as a usual param. Nope, the `retval` in the function doesn’t set the value for the global variable, it stays ‘Eeh’. No, there’s no `local` directive. It should be treated as global by default. If you put `test=1` to `check_params()` and `test=3` in `check_a_param()` and then print it with `echo $test`at the end of `setup()`, you should see 3. At least I do. `declare -g` doesn’t make any difference here, as expected.
- maybe that’s the scope of the function? No, that’s not it either. Moving `return_trap()` along with `declare -g retval=Eeh` doesn’t make any difference.
- when the modern software means fall, it’s time to resort to good old writing to a file. Let’s print the retval to /tmp/t with `retval=$?; echo $retval >/tmp/t` in `return_trap()` and read it back with

  `trap "return_trap; trap - RETURN; return $(</tmp/t)" RETURN`

Now we can finally see that the last return directive which reads the number from the file, actually returns 3. But `check_params()` still returns 0!

```
++ trap - RETURN
++ return 3
+ retval2=0
+ echo 'check_params() returned with 0. Not running manual setup.'
check_params() returned with 0. Not running manual setup.
```

---

If the argument to the `trap` command is strictly a function name, it returns the original result. The original one, not what `return_trap()` returns. I’ve tried to increment the result and still got 3.
You may also ask ‘Why would you need to unset the trap so much?’. It’s to avoid another bug, which causes the trap to trigger every time, even when `check_params()` is called from another function. Traps on RETURN are local things, they aren’t inherited by another functions unless there’s debug or trace flags explicitly set on them, but it looks like they keep traps set on them between runs. Or bash keeps traps for them. This trap should only be set when check_params() is called from a specific function, but if the trap is not unset, it continues to get triggered every time `check_a_param()` returns a value greater than zero independently of what’s in `FUNCNAME[1]`.

Here I give up, because the only exit I see now is to implement a check on the calling function before each `|| return $?` in `check_params()`. But it’s so ugly it hurts my eyes.

I may only add that, `$?` in the line setting the trap **will always return 0.** So, if you, for example, declare a `local` variable `retval` in `return_trap()`, and put such code to check it

```
trap "return_trap; [ -v retval ]; echo $?; trap - RETURN; return $retval" RETURN
```

**it will print 0 regardless** of whether `retval` is actually set or not, but if you use

```
trap "return_trap; [ -v retval ] && echo set || echo unset; trap - RETURN; return $retval" RETURN
```

It will print ‘unset’.

---

GNU bash, version 4.3.39(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: `trap "..."`, not `trap '...'`? At first glance, this smells to me like `$?` is being evaluated at definition time, vs invocation time, due to the quoting.

Comment: The idea that a function should behave differently depending on where is it being called from is quite appalling.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Funny enough,

```
trap "return_trap; trap - RETURN" RETURN
```

simply works.

```
[ ! -v MANUAL ] && {
    check_params; retval2=$?
    [ $retval2 -eq 0 ] \
        && echo "check_params() returned with 0. Not running manual setup." \
        || false
}|| ask_for_params
```

And here’s the trace.

```
+ check_a_parameter return_bad
+ '[' return_bad = return_ok ']'
+ return 3
+ return 3
++ return_trap
++ local retval=3
++ echo 3
++ '[' 3 -ne 0 ']'
++ echo 'Bad, bad… Dropping to manual setup.'
Bad, bad… Dropping to manual setup.
++ return 3
++ trap - RETURN
+ retval2=3
+ '[' 3 -eq 0 ']'
+ false
+ ask_for_params
+ echo 'User sets params manually step by step.'
User sets params manually step by step.
```

---

So the answer is simple: **do not try to overwrite the result** in the line passed to the `trap` command. Bash handles everything for you.